# editor list with valuesLookup returns single characters of list

Tags: tabulator

I trying to use the list editor with the valuesLookup. The closest solution I have found now is this question: [tabulator.js: list with valuelookup and custom ajax-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77941468/tabulator-js-list-with-valuelookup-and-custom-ajax-get).
Only issue I have is that it splits the returned list (['AA', 'BB', 'CC']) into single characters.
Any suggestions how to fix this?